# batch: any alternative method to kill goto loops?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

*premise* 
*Note that I convert those batch files in exes so I run no-ui (invisible) exes!*

I've created a simple goto loop in batch to keep killing WhatsApp, then I created another batch to stop that process and to be able to re-use WhatsApp again. 
 The fact is that to properly stop the goto loop I need to kill cmd.exe and conhost.exe, and, by doing this, I will terminate all the other goto loops that are running, or for example a cmd session I'm currently using.

e.g. 
If I have a copy of that batch that runs in background to lock another app, Telegram for example, by unlocking WhatsApp (so by killing cmd.exe and conhost.exe) I will also unlock Telegram.

---

Do you know any solutions? I was thinking about specific PIDs but I've got no idea of how to gather them, since they're generated casually everytime.

---

lockWS.bat

```
@echo off

:loop
taskkill /f /im WhatsApp.exe
goto loop
```

---

unlockWS.bat

```
@echo off

taskkill /f /im killWS.exe
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
taskkill /f /im conhost.exe
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Why not rename, move, or change the attributes of it?

Comment: Q: How often do you want to kill WhatsApp? A: YES! - You might want to check CPU load while this batch runs and then consider at least a `timeout 1` in the loop. You can also kill a cmd window by its title ( `taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq MyWindow"`).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use a file to get the parameters for which apps you wanna close, and change the file content as you need in run time.

This would be your loop script, you would run this just once:

```
@echo off
:loop

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Set your filename here, no need to be .txt
set "file=instructions.txt"

rem Read the file, split the values and run the command.
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%file%) do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do (
        taskkill /f /im %%b.exe
    )
)

rem wait 3 seconds before running again.
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
goto :loop
```

And this is the script you would run every time you wanna change the apps that should be closed:

```
rem Set the charset to UTF-8
chcp 65001 > nul 

rem write the parameters to the file.
echo whatsapp,telegram > instructions.txt
```

*Note 1: Specify the "instructions.txt" path if needed.*

*Note 2: The script above would work with comma as separator, but it's possible to implement to use another separator if you want.*

In this approach you wouldn't need to kill the cmd.exe every time you need to change the apps to be closed, you just need to change the instructions file and the loop.bat would get the new parameters.